# An extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ which contains the $n$-th roots of every element

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Consider $\mathbb{Q}$, the field of rational numbers.

Let $K_1\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be the (minimal) splitting field of the family $\{x^n-a\colon a\in\mathbb{Q}, n\geq 1\}$.

Let $K_2\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be the splitting field of the family $\{x^n-a\colon a\in K_1, n\geq 1\}$.

Contiinuing this we get an ascending chain $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq K_1\subseteq K_2\subseteq \cdots $ of subfields of $\mathbb{C}$.

Notice that $K_1, K_2,\cdots$ are algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, hence they are infact subfields of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Thus, $K=\cup_i K_i$ is a subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

**Question:** Is $K=\cup_i K_i$  a proper subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Comment: This is equivalent to the question whether all equations are solvable by taking radicals, and the answer is clearly no: the Galois group of any element of $K$ has a finite tower of cyclic extensions, but you can clearly construct an element such that its Galois group doesn't have this property, e.g. $A_n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every element in this field is solvable by radicals.

So in fact, we can not "write down" an algebraic number not in $K$, but thanks to Evariste Galois, we know it exists.

Comment: What if I take a polynomial of degree $n\geq 5$ whose splitting field has Galois group $S_n$. Then the roots of this polynomial all in $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ but not in  the extension $K$ right? Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean by "write down". Because a method like, say, Newton's method can yield us the roots of this polynomial up to an arbitrary degree  of precison AND we know it's minimal polynomial.

Comment: Findind the root numerically up to an arbitrary accuracy is not writing down the actual number, is it?

Comment: Is it not? Do the decimal digits of a number not completely determine the number itself? So what do we mean when we say we can "write down" the positive root of the polynomial $x^2-2$?

Comment: "Write down" in this context means $\sqrt 2$...Read about Galois theory and Solvability by radicals.

Comment: I see that they are not solvable by radicals, but "can not write down" makes it sound like the number is either not definable or not computable, which is certainly false. Besides $\sqrt 2$ is just short hand for the positive root of $x^2-2$ and conveys no new information that we cannot get from the minimal polynomial and an approximation of its location on the real line.

Comment: It is a clearly a matter of interpretation. And you claim that you know about solvability by radicals, so you should have known from the start how I meant that. Honestly, I do not understand why you even bothered to comment this at all and came up with the totally irrelevant Newton's method in this context...

Comment: I did not mean to offend. I was merely interested to know if there was a deeper meaning to your "write down". (+1)

Comment: Nevermind...Actually I just wanted to  point out the work of Galois there. For the question itself,  the first sentence of the answer already suffices.